# StaggeredGridView for Windows 8.1/10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to make a pinterest style GridView for windows 8.1/10 much like [this](http://www.appance.com/tag/staggeredgridview/) for android.

This will have images of different sizes and I only need the height to be variable. columns will be the same width.